# swap name and surename with that is spaced with ,

Tags: python, string

I am fetching names from tags in wikipedia like this:

```
k = BeautifulSoup(str(Position),"html.parser")         
name = k.find('a')['title']
```

names in this case will result in this

```
'Bassey, Charles'
```

Is there a way I can convert the names that are spaced like this to this:

```
'Charles Bassey'
```

Comment: Use `split()` to split it at the comma. Then swap the order of the two parts and join them back together. What did you try?

Comment: Try: `' '.join(name.replace(' ', '').split(',')[::-1])` (per Barmar comment).

Comment: @DarrylG what if i want to add an , to the string. so 'Charles, Bassey' how is that done? ' '.join(name.replace(' ', ', ').split(',')[::-1]) did not work

Comment: Please accept my answer below if it answered your question. If not comment on it so I might help further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
last_first = 'Bassey, Charles'
last_name,first_name  = last_first.split(',')
fullname = f'{first_name},{last_name}'
print(fullname)
```

output

```
Charles,Bassey
```